# How to get HttpContentHeaders from CloudBlockBlob?

Tags: .net, azure

When copying headers from a blob to a HttpContentHeader collection like this:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = blob.Properties.Length;
```

i was wondering if there was a way to get all the raw headers from CloudBlobBlob instead of copying them over like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
    static void ReadBlobProperties()
    {
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container-name");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");
        OperationContext opContext = new OperationContext();
        opContext.RequestCompleted += opContext_RequestCompleted;
        BlobRequestOptions requestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
        blob.FetchAttributes(null, requestOptions, opContext);

    }

    static void opContext_RequestCompleted(object sender, RequestEventArgs e)
    {
        var headers = e.Response.Headers;//e.Response.Headers will have all response headers
    }
```